# Header file causes problems with the original array after function call

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files

I created a header file called primes.h.
What I want is to call a function generate_primes() defined in this header file to fill an array with a determined number of prime numbers.

So to test if everything works fine, I first printed the elements of the array from 'inside' the header file' which works just fine. Then I tried printing them from outside the header file, in the program including the header file but it's not working, and the program just stops after printing a few elements.
Why is this unproper behaviour? And how can I do this the right way.
Thanks for helping.

The header file:

```
int generate_primes(const unsigned long long n, unsigned long long*prime) 
{

    try
        {
            prime = new unsigned long long[n]; 
        } 
    catch(const std::bad_alloc&e) {
        std::cerr << e.what(); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }

    prime[0] = 2, prime[1] = 3, prime[2] = 5; 

    unsigned long long p;
    unsigned long long index = 3;

    for (p = 7; index < n; p += 2)
        {
            short isPrime = 1; 
            unsigned long long test_limit = (unsigned long long) sqrt(p); 

            for (int i = 1; prime[i] <= test_limit && i < index; i++)
                {
                    if (!(p%prime[i]))
                        {
                            isPrime = 0; 
                            break;  
                        }   
                } 
            if (isPrime) prime[index++] = p; 
        }

    //everything works fine when I print from inside the header file 
    /*for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
      if (i && i % 7 == 0) std::cout << '\n'; 
      std::cout << prime[i] << "\t\t"; 
      }
    */
    return 1; 
}
```

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "primes.h"

int main(){
    unsigned long long n = 100;//example  
    unsigned long long *prime;   
    generate_primes(n, prime); 

    //but printing from here causes problems 
    //isn't the array now filled after calling the above function ? 
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            if (i && i % 5 == 0) std::cout<< '\n'; 
            std::cout << prime[i] << "\t"; 
        } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Don't put function definitions in header files.

Comment: Indentation is not something you should neglect this badly.

Comment: So what is the actual output of your program?

Comment: Sorry. I'll make sure I'll do that the next time.

Comment: Your problem is that the pointer parameter is only changed within the function but not reflected outside. You can change the parameter signature like this: `unsigned long long*&prime` to get your code working.

Comment: It prints a few elemnts and then It just stops working.

Comment: @Barmar Serious reasons why not?

Comment: Use std::vector instead of new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the parameter `prime` is being passed by value, not by reference. So when `generate_prime` assigns:

```
prime = new unsigned long long[n];
```

this only assigns to the local variable `prime`, not the caller's variable. You need to pass the parameter by reference so that the assignment will be visible to `main()`.

```
int generate_primes(const unsigned long long n, unsigned long long*&prime)
```

Comment: It would generally be better to just allocate the whole array at the caller's side and manage it's lifetime from there. Now it is unclear who and how should take care of the array. Then you wouldn't even have such issues.

Comment: @K.Kirsz And it would be even better to use `std::vector` so this whole thing becomes moot.

Comment: @K.Kirsz The _best way_ would be to use a `std::vector` reference parameter.

Comment: Thank's. I just meant to have this part of code seperated and be able to use It whenever I need It.

Comment: @lamriniyounes There's a lot of valid criticisms here you should pay attention to. Code separation is just one problem.

Comment: @lamriniyounes The proper way to do that is with a separate `.cpp` file, as in @tadman's answer. But the problem you're having is due to the incorrect function definition, not whether it's in a .cpp or .h file.

Comment: @Barmar Thank's for making this much clearer. I have just started learning C++ so I'm paying attention to everything you said.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a header file, it's a bunch of code. If you want to separate that code it should be in another `.cpp` file.

An associated `.h` would look like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <new>

int generate_primes(const unsigned long long n, unsigned long long*prime);
```

Then you'd have `generate_primes.cpp` or something like it:

```
 #include "generate_primes.h"

 int generate_primes(const unsigned long long n, unsigned long long*prime) {
   // (function body)
 }
```

To build your application you'd need to compile both `.cpp` files and link them together with the required libraries.

Comment: You're right, It's not. What I meant to do is to have this part of code seperated since I use It alot. Then be able to call It whenever I need It.

Comment: That's exactly why you break out your code into multiple `.cpp` files, and each `.cpp` with functions in it has an associated `.h` file that defines what those are. This complicates compilation, but you'll have to commit to a `Makefile`, or something like it eventually anyway. With a good compiler setup then only `.cpp` files which need to be recompiled will be compiled during a routine build, and this can speed up development considerably. the way you have it in the `.h` file leads to cascading rebuilds even if the function signature is untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the uninitialized pointer prime is an argument to the call of generate_primes. There it is not evaluated but the parameter assigned a new (local) value. Therefore inside the method the Array is accesible. But the new value is never returned, so in main the value of prime remains unchanged.

Additionally you should change n from unsingned long long to a smaller type for teh sake of the compiler.

Two possible solutions:
a) modify generate_prime so that it return the address of the Array

```
unsigned long long *prime generate_primes(const unsigned long n)
```

b) gíve the address of the pointer as an Argument to the method

```
int generate_primes(const unsigned long n, unsigned long long **prime) 
{

    try
    {
        *prime = new unsigned long long[n]; 
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc &e) {
    // your code
```

and

```
int main(){
    unsigned long n = 100;//example  
    unsigned long long *prime;   
    generate_primes(n, &prime);

    // your Code

    delete[] prime; // free memeory
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank's. I tried :  int generate_primes(const unsigned long long n, unsigned long long*&prime) wich is the same.